# How can I get a list of build targets in Ant?

Tags: ant

My codebase has a long `build.properties` file written by someone else. I want to see the available built targets without having to search through the file manually. Does ant have a command for this - something like `ant show-targets` - that will make it list all the targets in the build file?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

The `-p` or `-projecthelp` option does exactly this, so you can just try:

```
ant -p build.xml
```

From ant's command line [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html):

> The `-projecthelp` option prints out a list of the build file's targets. Targets that include a `description` attribute are listed as "Main targets", those without a `description` are listed as "Other targets", then the "Default" target is listed ("Other targets" are only displayed if there are no main targets, or if Ant is invoked in `-verbose` or `-debug` mode).

Comment: To make this the default when just invoking `ant`, create a target like
`<target name="help">
    <java classname="org.apache.tools.ant.Main">
        <arg value="-projecthelp" />
        <arg value="-buildfile" />
        <arg value="${ant.file}" />
    </java>
</target>`
and make "help" the default target in your project.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `ant -p` will only show targets that have descriptions.  To show every target associated with a `build.xml` file, you need to run `ant -p -v` Also, `ant -p build.xml` is redundant.  `ant -p` will do the same thing, and if you're not in the `build.xml` directory, you'll need to use `ant -p -buildfile path/to/build.xml`, anyway.

Comment: the `target name="help"` thing works fine, but not when run within Eclipse Ant environment (it just hangs, but `-diagnostics` or others are ok with it) :-( (no vm fork, Kepler with ant 1.8.4 (2014-05-22) and also tried with ant 1.9.4 (2014-04-29)) (just if you ask yourself ... I was creating a standalone ant env which I'd like to test within Eclipse ... of course I've got my *Ant View* there)

Answer (score 35):

To get all the targets in the build file

> ant -p -verbose

Comment: we need to use -p cominded with -v If we require all targets (by all targets i mean the targets without description in them as well) . if Only the main targets is required ( by Main targets i mean the ones with description in them ) using -p alone does the trick.

Comment: I couldn't see the targets that i need with only -p, this works perfect.

Answer (score 16):

The `-p` or `-projecthelp` option does exactly this, so you can do:

```
ant -p build.xml
```

You can make a target to invoke this like:

```
<target name="help">
    <java classname="org.apache.tools.ant.Main">
        <arg value="-projecthelp" />
        <arg value="-buildfile" />
        <arg value="${ant.file}" />
    </java>
</target>
```

which you can then set as the default, so just typing ant will list the available targets.

(Combining @Grodriguez' answer and @sschuberth's comment - I thought it was worth an answer by itself)

Comment: small suggestion. make "help" target as default. As a result running "ant" will invoke "help" target that will print all available targets.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the list of target and default target in build.xml by the following command

**ant -p built.xml**