# Ant build target to list own build targets

Tags: ant

I am brand new to Ant.  I would like to have the following:

```
<target name="targets" description "Lists Targets">
  [some Ant code/tasks]
</target
```

When I call `ant targets` I want Ant to search the current file that Ant is running for all it's targets

```
<target name="all" depends="doc,sca,compile,test" description="Complete build">
</target>
```

And output

```
[echo] all - Complete Build - Depends on: doc, sca, compile, test
[echo] doc - Builds documentation
[echo] compile - Compiles files
[echo] sca - Performs static code analysis
[echo] test - Runs unit tests - Depends on: compile
[echo] clean - Cleans a build
[echo] install - Performs an installation
[echo] targets - Lists Targets
```

In `Bash` or `Make` I'd just do a `grep` regular expression.  The following, in `Make`, lists the make targets:

```
noop: ;
targets:
    @$(MAKE) --print-data-base --question noop | \
     grep -v "[A-Z]:/" | \
     awk '/^[Mm]akefile:/           { next } \
         /^targets:/            { next } \
         /^noop:/           { next } \
         /^[^.%!][-A-Za-z0-9_]*:/   { print substr($$1, 1, length($$1)-1) }' | \
     sort | \
     pr --omit-pagination --width=80 --columns=4
```

Output:

```
[matt@office burning-boots-website]$ make -C ~/workspace/packages/ targets
all         diagnose        install         vca_core
clean           doc         platforms       vca_counting_line
compile         help        utils           vca_rules
```

It would be nice to have something simliar in my Ant build script!  would be especially nice if Ant could do the nice alignment that `pr` does - or even colour the output!  Can Ant do cross platform terminal colour changes?

Comment: is ant -p not sufficient, this command line option will list all targets? http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i see the available targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913638/how-do-i-see-the-available-targets)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `ant -p` (or `ant -p -v` to get more information). This won't list the target dependencies, but I don't see it as a problem: dependencies are not important for the end user (they just tell *how* the target works). What's important is *what* the target does, which is what should be in its description.

Comment: Perfect.  I assumed Ant had a method to print the targets but still crunching the documentation.